# Yii Framework - render form validation result in JSON format?

Tags: php, json, yii

I have form which I like to display the error msg & correct msg in a better UI, like icons with animation.

While using Yii framework, the error render is control by CActiveForm Class and I have no idea  how should I modify the echo format even after I read the code of Model Class.

I know you can set a message in rules() in the model Class, but it echo nothing if it pass the  validation. And i think is not a good idea for maintain when you need hard code the json format string as parameter like

```
'message'=>'{"name":"userName","result":"fail","msg":"already taken"},'
```

Comment: in Ajax validation ...?

Comment: I don't need it Asynchronous, I just need return message in JSON

Answer (score 0):

yes you can 
and here is an example my friend

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $contactForm = new ContactForm();
    $contactForm->body = "somehint ";
    $contactForm->validate(); // returns boolean; true or false. returns true if everything is okay . else false

    echo json_encode($contactForm->errors);
```

in your case it would be something like these

```
$myjsonValidationMessage = array();
$contactForm = new ContactForm();
if(!$contactForm->validate()){
$myjsonValidationMessage['message'] = $contactForm->errors;
echo json_encode($myjsonValidationMessage);
}
```